# website in SSL mode not working in firefox

Tags: apache, .htaccess, firefox, https

After https migration of my website,  the website works well on chrome, internet explorer and safari but not the case for firefox. 
The Html pages do not download all resources (css, js and images ...) I have 501 response
[See firefox developper tools screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8juC7.png)

I have also in the apache log file an errors like: 
[error] [client 88.219.231.11] Invalid method in request \x9dGET /medias/new-search.png HTTP/1.1, referer: https://www.

any idea please ?
I do not see where the HEX character **\x9d** comes from before the GET method?
And why I have this problem only with firefox?

NB: When I ask the html page several times the number of 501 error message in the development panel decreases

Answer (score 0):

I find the issue and i fixed it.
It come from wamp resources.(openSSL)
to fix it:
 -  I download the openSSL v1.1.0 [from this link](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)  
 - Install it 
 - In the installed directory, copy the files (bin\openssl.cfg, bin\libeay32.dll bin\ssleay32.dll) and paste it into bin/apacheVersion/bin/ (to remplace the old files) 
 - rename the copied file openssl.cfg to openssl.cnf 
 - Restart wamp